# android phonegap - what path to write in my <img src="?">?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

in my index.html, I want to show a picture, but no matter what path i give to the src attribute, it wont show it. Does it have to be on the phone?
Im using JQuery mobile for the styles.

```
<div data-role="page" id="start" >
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>

<div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
<p>Lorem ipsum and so on</p>
<img src="/HelloPhonegap/res/drawable-hdpi/goat.jpg" alt="me during last summer vacation"/>
</div>

</div>
```

the current path of the src attribute is where the picture is stored. What can I do here?
I know it´s not the JPEG, because when I link a jpg from somewhere in the internet, the pic is shown. What do I miss here?
best regards daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android: You put your html/js project in the assets/www folder and for example the image in assets/www/img/goat.jpg.

if your html file is in assets/www/ you just use

```
<img src="img/goat.jpg" alt="me during last summer vacation"/>
```

build the app and PhoneGap does the magic.